# Issues with Dropdown Menu function with Data-toggles (TB)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I've found this site useful for whenever I get in trouble with my code not working properly, however I haven't been able to find a fix (or figure out whats wrong with my code) so I decided to finally make an account.

I'm not programmer and I don't know Javascript so I'm using HTML, CSS, and TB (Twitter Bootstrap) to kind of cheat so that when I choose an option, it can display objects without having to redirect to a new HTML page.

The issue is that I got the code to work properly using Nav Tabs but I'm trying to make it so that a drop down button can have the same function, but can also be functional on a extra small device (phone). The drop down menu works, but for some reason it keeps the previously selected option highlighted (when trying to choose a new option) and cannot be selected again without reloading the page. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance!

My code is:

> ```
> <div class="btn-group">
> <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button"
> data-toggle="dropdown"> Designs and Concepts <span class="caret"></span>
> </button>   
>
>
>  <ul class="dropdown-menu"id="myTab">
> <li><a href="#test1" data-toggle="tab">Test1</a></li>    
> <li><a href="#test2" data-toggle="tab">Test2</a></li>
> <li><a href="#test3" data-toggle="tab">Test3</a></li> 
>  </ul> </div>
>
>  <div class="tab-content"> <div class="tab-pane fade in active"></div> 
>  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="test1">
>  <img class="img-responsive"src="#"></img>
>  <p>This is the first test section/p></div>
>
>  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="test2">
>  <img class="img-responsive"src="#" style="width:250px;"></img>
>  <p>This is the second test section.</p></div>
>
>  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="test3">
>  <img src="#"></img>
>  <p>This is the third test section</p>
>  </div></div> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest your unordered list in another unordered list.

1) Delete your `<div class="btn-group">` and insert `<ul id="myTab" class="nav">`

2) Under that line insert `<li class="dropdown active">`

3) Delete `id="myTab"` from `<ul class="dropdown-menu"id="myTab">`

4) Close `</li>` and `</ul>`

5) For your `<div class="tab-content">` you can clean up the code a bit by removing the `in` class and the `</img>`. `<img>` is a stand alone tag and does not need a closing tag see code below for example.

See below code:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav">
   <li class="dropdown active">
   <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Designs and Concepts <span class="caret"></span></button>  
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class=""><a href="#test1" data-toggle="tab">Test1</a></li>
       <li class=""><a href="#test2" data-toggle="tab">Test2</a></li>
       <li class=""><a href="#test3" data-toggle="tab">Test3</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content"> 
    <div class="tab-pane fade active"></div> 
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="test1">
        <img class="img-responsive"src="#" />
        <p>This is the first test section/p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="test2">
        <img class="img-responsive"src="#" style="width:250px;" />
        <p>This is the second test section.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="test3">
        <img src="#" />
        <p>This is the third test section</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: You are awesome! 

Haha I spent about 2.5 hours trying to figure out what was wrong and it makes total sense now. As for the <img></img> good catch, this code is fairly old I've just been going back and trying to migrate everything from bootstrap 2 to bootstrap 3.

Thanks again, this website has yet to let me down.

Comment: You are welcome. I was a bit confused at first cause your code was mostly correct. Glad I could help.